# Changing font color in SSMS for different database elements?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to change font color of different database elements, for database name to show up one color, table name to show up another and table aliases to be separate color. Is it even possible? Thanks

I'm using SSMS 2012. I have been experimenting with Fonts and Colors setting for Text Editor but I can't find a way to make different elements unique colors.